# How can I detect screenshots?

Tags: windows

I was wondering if a program can check if another (unknown) process is taking screenshots regularly?

System: windows 7 environment. My program is a java program that takes screenshots ( say 100 per hour) . Another process might be trying to detect this. I was wondering if this is possible

Comment: Please give more context:  On a mobile phone yes there are ways to detect this obviously.  On a windows system yes there are to, but which are you thinking of.

Comment: Voted to move this to StackOverflow because it seems like a programming question ("How do I do X") and although the topic has security-related implications, it's not a question *about* IT security. If others agree (and vote the same) it will be moved automatically, you do *not* need to create a new question there. It's a good question, though.

Comment: The only reason I can think of, why you need to know, is, to prevent it. If that is the case, you can prevent an application to take screenshots, without knowing that they are trying. It's a simple matter of calling [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx), passing a `WDA_MONITOR` *dwAffinity* argument.

Comment: This looks so much as someone trying to spy on others!

Comment: You can only get some assurance of it. An external device could take a screen shot and there is no way to detect that.